# Activity onCreate() and onNewIntent() race condition

Tags: android, android-activity

Is it possible that onNewIntent() and onCreate() will be called on the same Activity instance with a short delay?

Do I need to synchronize my code between those two methods?

Comment: There's no race condition because both of those callbacks are executed on main looper.

Comment: @Pawel But what if I will run this code on a separate thread? Or launch it using ViewModel Coroutine Scope?

Comment: Unless you've calling lifecycle callbacks methods directly (which you should never do) it will never happen because requests to `startActivity` are not blocking - they're parsed and dispatched by the system.